# how can i make it to accept the floating ponit number

Tags: java, eclipse

My problem is in code it is not accepting the floating point digit 
So should i make any changes in code part pls suggest me..

{
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "320.9"

```
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at org.lrap.otc.OTCVerification.verifyOtc(OTCVerification.java:26)
```

//code part//int bill=Integer.parseInt(strArray[2].trim());

```
at org.lrap.main.Main.run(Main.java:68)
```

//code part//boolean retVal=OTCVerification.getOTCVerificationObj().verifyOtc(message);

```
at org.lrap.main.Main.main(Main.java:111)
```

just calling the run function
}
thank u to all who r assisting me.:-)

Comment: You should show us the code also, exceptions are not enough

Answer (score 1):

> For input string: "320.9"
>
> at java.lang.**Integer.parseInt**(Unknown Source)

Use `Double.parseDouble` to parse numbers with fractions.  Not `Integer.parseInt`.

If the input might not be a machine formatted number, then you should use [`DecimalFormat.parse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition%29) with an appropriate Locale to recognize numbers formatted using the local convention (320,9 in parts of Europe for example).

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want a floating point number, use [`Double.parseDouble`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29) or [`new BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

```
double target = Double.parseDouble(theString);
// Or
BigDecimal target = new BigDecimal(theString);
```

If you want an integer, use [`String#indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29) to find the `.`, then use [`String#substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) to get only the digits before the `.`, and continue using `Integer.parseInt`.

```
int index = theString.indexOf('.');
if (index >= 0) {
    theString = theString.substring(0, index);
}
int target = Integer.parseInt(theString);
```

Or, as [Mike Samuel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20394/mike-samuel) points out in the comments below, use `Double.parseDouble` and then cast to `int`:

```
int target = (int)Double.parseDouble(theString);
```

Comment: There's no need to muck around with `indexOf` and `substring` unless the integer part won't fit in a `double` mantissa.  Just parse as a `double` then down-cast to an `int` which will round towards zero.

Comment: @MikeSamuel: Sure, I can see that approach. I think I'd still isolate the string I want to parse, and then parse it with the right method, but as you say that should work too. And since you get 15 digits or so of precision in a `double`, and the max `int` is 2,147,483,647 (13 digits), you shouldn't run into mantissa issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
Integer.parseInt(String s)
```

is used to convert a valid string to integer.And the value should be between -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.It wont accept any floationg point number.

For converting to floating point , you can use `Double.parseDouble or new BigDecimal.`

Answer (score 0):

To convert a "floating point digit", you should also be aware of the used [`NumberFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html). If you are converting the String "320.9", you are fine in most locales. If your program is running on a "french" machine, a floating point digit might come in as "320,9".

Double.parse works only with "." as delimiter (correctly speaking, it depends on sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(String in)). So, if you can rely on having that delimiter, you are fine with [`Double.parse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29)

If you have to deal with both cases, you may use something like this:

```
final String num = "320,9";
final NumberFormat nf_french = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRENCH); // French Number Format (= xxx,yyy) 
final double result_french = nf_french.parse(num).doubleValue(); // => 320.9
final NumberFormat nf_us = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US); // US Number Format (= xxx.yyy) 
final double result_us = nf_us.parse(num).doubleValue(); // => 3209.0 !!
```